# AC field propulsion

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science, electrical-engineering, metamaterials

Assuming that we have a metamaterial that can slow down the velocity of propagation of changes in an EM field to around 15 000 m/s (without felling or applying any forces),  can we build a propulsion system with two high frequency electromagnets with this material in between them?
Because when the field interacts with the other electromagnet, the first is already off, not felling the reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get the picture correctly, then the problem is that the metamaterial will also respond to changes in the EM field. That's in fact what makes it slow light down.
So it doesnt matter how fast you change the field, your system will excert an opposite force not allowing it to move forward.